# Get Angular ngRepeat InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I would like to know how to get the **Full, Plain HTML** of an **Angular ngRepeat**.
I need it to create reports, alert part of code etc.

I used the $compile and I've been able to get the HTML of simple tags by compiling

```
<p>I am {{surname}}, {{name}} {{surname}}</p>
```

and what I got is

```
<p>I am Bond, James Bond<p>
```

But when I try to do the same with

```
<p ng-repeat="number in array">{{number}}</p>
```

I only get the Angular comment saying

```
<!-- ngRepeat -->
```

Instead of the series of paragraphs.
Please check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/d4p0qLx2/) for examples.

Comment: You should not be trying to modify `ng-repeat` or other Angular generated output with jQuery.

Comment: why do you require the html content of the element?

Comment: I don't want to modify it, I want to get the plain HTML for other purposes (alerts, create a report etc)

Comment: Could you explain your downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order Angular to compile ngRepeat directive it must be in DOM. Angular finds corresponding comment and replaces it with actual HTML structure.

So all you need to do is to append compiled comment node to DOM and after it's rendered you can retrieve HTML.

```
$scope.html = $compile('<p ng-repeat="el in arr">{{el}}</p>')($scope);
document.getElementById('app').appendChild($scope.html[0]);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d4p0qLx2/2/

And in the next digest cycle you can get rendered HTML: **http://jsfiddle.net/d4p0qLx2/4/**

Comment: Thank you! I missed the timeout thing.